# Mongoose - mapping json object to Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to learn mongo/mongoose and am importing json into mongodb.

My json contains a number of objects of the form:

```
{
   "FIELD1": "28/02/2017",
   "FIELD2": "string value",
   "FIELD3": "100"
 },
 {
   "FIELD1": "28/02/2017",
   "FIELD2": "string",
   "FIELD3": "57"
 },
```

I have a schema:

```
var statementSchema = new Schema({
   //date: {type:Date, required: true},
   //name : {type:String, required:true},
   //amount: {type: Number, required:true}
   FIELD1 : {type:String, required:true},
   FIELD2: {type:String, required:true},
   FIELD3: {type:String, required:true}
});
```

You can see that I would really like the keys in the db to be more descriptive of the values they contain than they are in the source json (i.e. I would prefer `FIELD1` in the json to be `date` in the DB).

What is the best way to do this?  I have seen mongoose-aliasfield, is that the best approach or is there a default way to define FIELD1 `as` someothername in the Schema?

While I have you, what's the correct way to cast FIELD1 and FIELD3 as `Date` and `Number` respectively from their current String in the json source? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so this was me being a newb really.

Schema is now defined:

```
var statementSchema = new Schema({
date : {type:Date, required:true},
name: {type:String, required:true},
amount: {type:Number, required:true}
});
```

and I insert using:

```
var statements= require('../data/convertcsv.json');
var Statement = require('../models/statement');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('localhost:27017/statement');

var parseDate = require('../helpers/parseDate');


var done = 0;
for( var i = 0; i < statements.length; i++ ) {
var newStatement = new Statement();
//helper function breaks string apart, reassembles and returns a Date
newStatement.date = parseDate.stringToDate(statements[i].FIELD1);
newStatement.name = statements[i].FIELD2;
newStatement.amount = Number(statements[i].FIELD3);

newStatement.save(function(err, result){
    done++;
    if(done === statements.length){
        exit();
    }
});

}

function exit(){
mongoose.disconnect();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this way., ref [Mongoose schema data type](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html).

**schema:**

```
var statementSchema = new Schema({
   FIELD1 : {type:Date, required:true},
   FIELD2: {type:String, required:true},
   FIELD3: {type:Number, required:true}
});
```

**Insert:**

```
db.getCollection('users').save({
   "FIELD1": Date("28/02/2017"),
   "FIELD2": String("string"),
   "FIELD3": Number("57")
 })
```

**result:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58f8ba663749f1f13fee40d6"),
    "FIELD1" : "Thu Apr 20 2017 19:10:54 GMT+0530 (IST)",
    "FIELD2" : "string",
    "FIELD3" : 57.0
}
```

Comment: thanks for this.  But wouldn't the above just define the type that field needs to be? If I'm importing from a source that has that value as a String will the also cast to `Date` etc?

Comment: thanks.  And regarding the options to have different keys in the schema definition than in the input json is this the only/best option https://github.com/ramiel/mongoose-aliasfield